# XenCenter displays sometimes that the XenServer Tools has not been installed

Tags: xen, xenserver

When I restart a Windows VM then it happens quite often that the XenCenter displays this message even the XenServer Tools are installed:

[image]

When I restart the VM then the message is gone. I tried it for this post and now the message disappeared:

[image]

Has someone any idea what it can be? Is it a XenServer bug or was something not correctly installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a display bug/by design from citrix. As when the xencenter cant communicate with the xentool in the virtualmachine when the machine boot it display that by default.

It could have display unknown, but the designer decided to display the message that its not installed.

When the machine is loaded and the xentool service is up, this is when the message disapear.

Comment: May be I should just polite report it to Citrix and they fix it?

Comment: You can ask if you got a support contract with them! else it cost high to be able to talk to them